# my redis keys do not expire

Tags: redis, ttl, cache-expiration

My redis server does not delete keys when the time-to-live reaches 0.

Here is a sample code:

```
redis-cli
>SET mykey "ismykey"
>EXPIRE mykey 20
#check TTL
>TTL mykey
>(integer) 17
> ...
>TTL mykey
>(integer) -1
#mykey chould have expired:
>EXISTS mykey
>(integer) 1
>#oh still there, check its value
>GET mykey
>"ismykey"
```

If i check the info return by redis, it says 0 keys were expired.

Any idea?

thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Since you're doing a '...' it's hard to say for sure, but I'd say you're setting mykey during that part, which will effectively remove the expiration.

[From the EXPIRE manual](http://redis.io/commands/expire)

> The timeout is cleared only when the key is removed using the DEL
>   command or overwritten using the SET or GETSET commands

[Also, regarding the -1 reply from TTL](http://redis.io/commands/ttl)

> Return value
>
> Integer reply: TTL in seconds or -1 when key does not
>   exist or does not have a timeout.

**EDIT: Note that this behaviour changed in Redis 2.8**

> Starting with Redis 2.8 the return value in case of error changed:
>   The command returns -2 if the key does not exist.
>   The command returns -1 if the key exists but has no associated expire.

In other words, if your key exists, it would seem to be persistent, ie not have any expiration set.

EDIT: It seems I can reproduce this if I create the key on a REDIS slave server, the slave will not delete the key without master input, since normally you would not create keys locally on a slave. Is this the case here?

> However while the slaves connected to a master will not expire keys
>   independently (but will wait for the DEL coming from the master),
>   they'll still take the full state of the expires existing in the
>   dataset, so when a slave is elected to a master it will be able to
>   expire the keys independently, fully acting as a master.

Comment: Thanks for your so quick reply. The '...' in my snippet only meant that I wait 20s until the TTL returns -1. I don't type any command here. So the expiration should go til its end, no?

Comment: thanks Joachim! That is exactly the point, I unintentionally set my key on the slave instead of the master, which is inconsistent.  If i switch to my master everything works fine.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson `"TTL in seconds or -1 when key does not exist or does not have a timeout."` Does it not return -2 if the key does not exist?

Comment: @Djack Apparently the behavior changed after my answer was written, added an edit with the new behavior, thanks.

Comment: I also faced similar issue once I create keys on slave. In my case redis TTL was giving 0 and it was not deleting the key. My redis version is 2.8